# jquery UI resizable with set timeout and clear timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, image-resizing

Hi I'm having problems with jquery resizable function or perhaps a callback,

basically, the div is expanded depends on the image inside it, after few seconds it will collapse.

my goal is whenever I touch the handle the setTimeout should be cleared and stop . because right now whenever I open the image it will collapse again and the setTimeout still runs.

and also the window resize is not as smooth as I want. the parent container should always follow the image height.. please see my sample code at

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var imgMain = $(".img-pushdown"),
       frameTwo;

   imgMain.load(function(){
    var imageHeight = this.height,
    imageContainer = $("#pushdown-custom");

    function pushdown_collapse(){
     imageContainer.stop(true, false).animate({height:40},1000);
    }

    frameTwo = setTimeout(function(){
     pushdown_collapse();
    },10000);

    imageContainer.resizable({
     start: function( event, ui ) {
     clearTimeout(frameTwo);
    },
    handles: {'s': '#handle'},
    minHeight: 40,
    maxHeight: imageHeight
   });
  });
 });

$(window).on('resize', function(){
 $(".img-pushdown").trigger('load');
}).trigger('resize');
});

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yr3kdccm/

Comment: Hi, it is not clear what you're trying to do. Instead of explaining the problem with you're code, could you please explain what you're trying to achieve..?

Comment: I updated the code https://jsfiddle.net/wqgjkt3t/ , after 10 secs it will collapsed. then, you can hold the red bar to expand and collapse it again. the question now is when you expand it manually and resized the window, the container height is not resonsive